# WebGL Vertex shader scale geometry regardless of aspect in orthographic projection

Tags: glsl, webgl, vertex-shader

I have a problem with geometry scale in vertex shader. I have an orthographic projection and would like the text to be same sized (on screen) regardless of zoom. I managed to do it with:

```
position.xy *= scale2d(vec2(0.005 / projectionMatrix[0].x, 0.005 / projectionMatrix[1].y));
```

position is in local space. It works correctly, but only when viewport is a square (looking at orthographic projection matrix formula, that's reasonable). When viewport is rectangular I get a stretched geometry (in this case aspect around 1.4 and stretched by x-axis):

[image]

I tried to divide x coordinate by aspect, and that partially resolved the issue:

```
position.xy *= scale2d(vec2(0.005 / projectionMatrix[0].x / aspect, 0.005 / projectionMatrix[1].y));
```

That works in terms of preserving aspect, but when I resize viewport's y-axis, the geometry gets shrinked/enlarged (again - it's reasonable, because height - projectionMatrix[1].y shrinks). I'd like it to have same size regardless of viewport dimensions.

Could someone explain how to achieve the effect I want?
BTW. I also wonder why 0.005 factor is correct.

EDIT: so basically I know that I want the text to have let's say 12px height in screen coords. How to scale it preserving the aspect?